# Why my hook_block_view doesn't work?

Tags: 7, blocks, hooks

I installed "Form block" and it creates blocks. I want change block title via my module, but it doesn't work.

I create module and set function with hook_block_view:

```
function zzz_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'user_register':
      global $user;
      // Don't display the form to logged in users or if registration is disabled
      if (!$user->uid && variable_get('user_register', 1)) {
        $block['content']['form'] = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
        $block['subject'] = t('MY TITLE IS HERE');
      }
      return $block;
  }
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hook_block_view()` is only invoked for the module that defines the block via `hook_block_info()`.

To alter the content of a block provided by another module, use [`hook_block_view_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7.x) instead.

Comment: I tried use hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter instead hook_block_view_alter() but can't achieve result =(

Comment: It should do - MYMODULE_block_view_user_user_register_alter right?

Comment: I did like that function mymodule_block_view_user_register_alter(&$data, $block) {
$data['subject'] = 'lallal';
}

Comment: The module's called `user`, the delta is `user_register`, so the string is `user_user_register`. You're missing a `user`. The example in the previous comment should work

Comment: Unfortunately, it also doesn't work =(